# Rails: How to set object of form dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A normal form for person will be like this

```
<%= form_for @person do |f|%>
  <%= name... %>
  <%= age...%>
  <%= submit...%>
<% end %>
```

Now I want to set the object of form dynamically, select from a dropdown list, like

```
<%= select_tag "team",
   options_from_collection_for_select(@team, 
  "id","person_name") %>


<%= form_for @person_choose_from_above do |f|%>
  <%= name... %>
  <%= age...%>
  <%= submit...%>
<% end %>
```

How to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the selection will be done in the view, you should use JS for that to modify form attributes.

Comment: It really depends on how you want the form to behave: do you want it to dynamically update the fields as you select different options in team? Then updating them through js/ajax is probably your best bet. Maybe you could just put the select in the form, and handle everything in the controller, which wouldn't be very dynamic? It depends...

Answer (score 0):

You can use  like this

Create a enum on your active recored

```
class ClassName < ActiveRecord::Base
enum team: [:hot, :medium, :cold];
```

Then use this on your view like this

```
<%= f.label :team %>
<%= f.select :team, ClassName.team.keys %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this: on team select reload the page passing the parameter of selected option and then reinitializing the person's object.

Views:

```
<%= form_tag("/url", method: "get") do %>
  <%= select_tag "team", 
    options_from_collection_for_select(@team, 
    "id","person_name"), name: 'team' %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search"), class: 'fake-submit', style: 'display: none;' %>
<% end %>
<% person = params[:team].present? ? Person.find(params[:team]) : Person.new %>

<%= form_for (person) do |f|%>
  <%= name... %>
  <%= age...%>
  <%= submit...%>
<% end %>
```

Javascript:

```
$('select').on 'change', ->
 $('.fake-submit').click()
```